# pygame movement of character in Class does not work

Tags: python, class, pygame, game-physics

I am new to developing games. Before I used to place the movement of the main character in the while loop and it worked perfectly. Now I am trying to make a Class for the maincharacter as in can be seen in the code below (I was told it is better because the collision will be easier and less messy to program). However, I am not able to make the character to move (including the camera). Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am pretty sure it is a small mistake which I can not figure out.

This is just part of my game. But I just want you to see what I do with the movement of the maincharater. This part of the code should display background and image of the maincharater and after it the maincharacter is supposed to move around when the arrow keys are pressed (including the camera).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("No Name")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 1)
Background = pygame.image.load('desert.png')
mainCharacterImage = pygame.image.load('main character (front).png')

x = 626
y = 384
CameraX = x-400
CameraY = y-300
key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()



class mainCharacter():
    def __init__(self, x, y, CameraX, CameraY):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x-CameraX,y-CameraY,30,30)

    def drawMainCharacter(self, event, x, y, CameraX, CameraY, mainCharacterImage):
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 2
            CameraX -= 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 2
            CameraX += 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= 2
            CameraY -= 2
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += 2
            CameraY += 2

        gameDisplay.blit(mainCharacterImage,(x - CameraX, y - CameraY))


Exit = False

while (not Exit):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Exit = True
    mainCharacterCoordinates = mainCharacter(x,y,CameraX,CameraY)
    mainCharacterCoordinates.drawMainCharacter(event,x,y,CameraX,CameraY,mainCharacterImage)
    gameDisplay.blit(Background,(-2000 - CameraX, -600 - CameraY))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two major issues with your code.

1. You initialize `key_pressed` at the start. This means that it will never change. Move `key_pressed` into your main loop and pass that information into `drawMainCharacter()` to ensure that it checks each frame if a key is pressed
2. You initialize `x` and `y` at the start and never update it. This will cause your position to update and draw using `drawMainCharacter(x,y)` for a single frame. On the next loop the starting `x` and `y` will be passed in and the character will snap back to it's starting position! I suggest initializing `x` and `y` within the character object, and not giving the main loop access to that info. Pass the key_pressed and allow the character to update it's position. There is no need for the loop to know this position!

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work :(
I created inside the character object the coordinates.
I put the key_pressed inside the loop,
and I pass the key_pressed to the function.